# Calculating $\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\operatorname{ali}(x)}{x^3}dx$, where $\operatorname{ali}(x)$ is the inverse function of the logarithmic integral

Tags: nt.number-theory, real-analysis, integration, asymptotics, special-functions

It is well-known that we can compute the closed-form of the integrals $$\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\log x}{x^2}dx$$
and $$\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\operatorname{li} (x)}{x^3}dx,$$
where $\operatorname{li} (x)$ is the logarithmic integral. On the other hand we know that was defined in the literature its inverse and denoted as $\operatorname{ali}(x)$, for example see in [1], since by definition (I write this sentence to clarify/emphasize the notation)
$$\operatorname{li}(\operatorname{ali}(x))=x,$$
for my purpose I take in this post $x\geq 1$.

As **motivation** for previous integrals (at least from my point of view) and next questions we've the Theorem 3.3 from [1].

> **Question 1. (Answered in comments by numerical computations)** I wondered what about the definite integral $$\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\operatorname{ali}(x)}{x^3}dx\,?\tag{1}$$
> That I am asking is if you can provide a reference or if it isn't in the literature a good calculation of $(1)$.

I've splitted my question in two parts, if you want to add also a contribution for previous **Question 1** feel free to do it (I don't know if one can to justify easily that $\int\frac{\operatorname{ali}(x)}{x^3}dx$ is a nonelementary integral).

> **Question 2.** I would like to know a concise calculation to know what about the asymptotic behaviour of $$\int_1^X\frac{\operatorname{ali}(x)}{x^3}dx$$
> as $X\to\infty$. **Many thanks.**

I hope that it is a good question for this site, if the integral is in the literature then feel free to add the reference and I try to search and read the corresponding statement from the literature.

### Reference:

[1] J. Arias de Reyna and J. Toulisse, *[The n-th prime asymptotically](https://doi.org/10.5802/jtnb.847)*, J. Théor. Nombres Bordeaux 25 (2013), 521–555.

Comment: FWIW, Mathematica evaluates this to approximately $1.741$.

Comment: Many thanks @YiFan

Comment: As noted, this is easy to calculate numerically in *Mathematica*, if you don't need a closed form: `With[{x0 = Quiet[\[FormalX] /. First[Solve[LogIntegral[\[FormalX]] == 1 && 1 < \[FormalX] < 2, \[FormalX]]]]}, NIntegrate[x/(Log[x] LogIntegral[x]^3), {x, x0, Infinity}, WorkingPrecision -> 100]]`, which yields 1.741935272650614694748847046710991610055712810369420527260197272782982526318585249616925251489695552.

Comment: Many thanks for your contribution @J.M.isnotamathematician

Comment: @J.M.isn'tamathematician I've splitted the question in two parts, feel free to edit your answer  for **Question 1** if you consider it. Many thanks again for you, and for the other person in comments.

Comment: for what it worth, the integral equals $a/2+\int_a^\infty \frac{dt}{2 {\rm li}^2(t)}$, where ${\rm li}(a)=1$.

Comment: Many thanks for this contribution @FedorPetrov